# Is it possible to search on Google at a particular time point in the past?

Tags: google-search

I am trying to retrieve a Google result I looked up a while back.

I know what the exact search query is, however, the same search query now shows different results, as Google results keep changing over time.

Therefore, is it possible to search on Google at a particular time point in the past?

Answer (score 1):

No, as you noted, doing a search query on Google from a past point in time doesn't return the same results nowadays.

The differences can be subtle or drastic because of a multitude of factors that are changing moment by moment including but not limited to Google's algorithms and indexes, cached images, and various user environment-related parameters.

The act of performing a search in and of itself will impact the results of the same search if repeated.

Google doesn't document a way to recreate a past search with identical results, and it is counter-intuitive given the host of variables that influence search results at any point in time.

Answer (score -2):

Look if this answers your question. Also I recommend using reverse image search engines other than Google, like TinEye.

[image]

Comment: Hi. It seems like there was a misunderstanding. I would like to simulate a Google (specifically, Google Images) search query as if I'm searching in the past, not giving an image I already have and finding its source.